# C++ generic functions flexibility

Tags: c++, templates

I want to make flexible generic function which its return can deal with more than one unknown type.

```
#include <iostream>

template<typename U, typename V>
U Max(U arg1, V arg2) {
    return arg1 > arg2 ? arg1 : arg2;
}

using namespace std;
int main()
{
    double x = 9.88;
    int  n = 8;
    cout << Max(x, n) << endl; // output is 9.88
    int z = 4;
    double r = 5.88;
    // output is 5 not 5.88, I want to code one function deal with all types.
    cout << Max(z, r) << endl; 
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Well then you have to figure out what you want to do with different types? Should one be promoted? If so, to which type?

Comment: Well, you have to decide for one particular type used as return value type (and document that one clearly). As you've chosen `int` in your sample, it's `int` in the output. Not sure, if there are SFINAE tricks are viable, to prefer `double` over `int` to be used as the return type.

Answer (score 6):

You can use [`std::common_type`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/common_type),

```
template<typename U,typename V>
typename std::common_type<U, V>::type 
Max(U arg1, V arg2){
    return arg1 > arg2 ? arg1 : arg2;
}
```

Comment: That's a really good pointer. Would it prefer `double` vs `int` type for any arbitrary combination of `U` and `V`?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I believe so, at least according to the cppreference link.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Yeah, `common_type_t<int, double>` is `double`.

Answer (score 2):

You have to determine a return type, too.

Maybe:

```
template<typename U, typename V>
auto Max(U arg1, V arg2) -> decltype(arg1 + arg2)
{
    return arg1 > arg2 ? arg1 : arg2;
}
```

You can use any pair of two classes (types) supporting the operators < and +.

Note: This assumes an arithmetic expression 'a + b' is valid if you can apply the operator 'a < b'. (Please notice the comment of @Barry)

Comment: So `Max('a', 'b')` returns an `int`?

Comment: @BarryYep: Not harmful when dealing with arithmetic expressions.

Comment: In C++14, just omit the trailing return type and let `auto` return type deduction take over.  It will deduce `char`.  In C++11, you could use `decltype(arg1 > arg2 ? arg1 : arg2)` instead.  If you do this, then this solution is actually equivalent to @vsoftco's per the standard's definition of  `std::common_type`.